# How to approach exposing DCOM using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, dcom

I'm after a steer on how to expose a DCOM component using WCF. I'm hoping for some expertise to point me in the right direction and therefore help me save time (tight deadline).

I have yet to receive any information on the DCOM, the Server and the applications that use it. In fact I'm light on any knowledge about the current configuration. I do know that they'll be looking to place a web service in front of it so they can avoid costs in getting the supplier to integrate (point-to-point) any future applications.

This is an in-house project using developers with basic .NET skills so if anyone can provide details on the information they'll need to capture, the skills they'll need and the approach they should take it'd be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think if there is any way to expose DCOM components . If that is a COM+ then you can find something on COM+ apps as WCF services.

If you have com+ . Here is a link that can help you out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735856.aspx

It seems you may have to re write your application. Look at the following link if this can help you some how.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188746.aspx

I hope this helps.

Thanks.